# Polymorphism in XStream serialization and deserialization

Tags: java, xstream

I have these classes:

```
@XStreamAlias("person")
public class PersonConfig {

    private AnimalConfig animalConfig;

}

public interface AnimalConfig {}

@XStreamAlias("dog");
public class DogConfig extend AnimalConfig {}

@XStreamAlias("cat");
public class CatConfig extend AnimalConfig {}
```

And I would like to be able to deserialize this xml with the classes above:

```
<person>
    <dog/>
<person>
```

As well as deserialize this xml too, with the same classes:

```
<person>
    <cat/>
<person>
```

So that in both cases, the `PersonConfig`'s field `animalConfig` is filled. In the first XML with a `DogConfig` instance and in the second XML with a `CatConfig` instance.

Is this possible by adding some annotation to make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems XStream does not allow you to do it easily.

Your question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3735254/xstream-to-map-choice-elements-of-xml), asking for managing something like a xsd:choice with XStream.

If you don't necessarily need to use XStream, JAXB will allow you to do it easily :

```
@XmlRootElement(name="person")
public class PersonConfig {

    private AnimalConfig animalConfig;

    @XmlElementRefs({
        @XmlElementRef(name="cat", type=CatConfig.class),
        @XmlElementRef(name="dog", type=DogConfig.class)
    })
    public AnimalConfig getAnimalConfig() {
        return animalConfig;
    }

    public void setAnimalConfig(AnimalConfig animalConfig) {
        this.animalConfig = animalConfig;
    }
}
```

After some researches, listing all available classes for your property can be avoided if you choose to use the `XmlAdapter`.
In Blaise Doughan link, the example uses an abstract class, not an interface.

**Edit :**

As Blaise Doughan said in its comment, `@XmlElementRef` is better suited for this purpose. Code has been updated accordingly.

Comment: +1 - However I would recommend using `@XmlElementRef` since that corresponds to the XML schema concept of substitution groups, instead of `@XmlElements` which is used to map choice structures:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/11/jaxb-and-inheritance-using-substitution.html

Comment: Yes you're right. I didn't knew `@XmlElementRef` and I read your (great) post on it. I will update my answer. Thx !

Answer (score 1):

You can write a converter.

```
public class CustomConverter implements Converter {

   public void marshal(Object source, HierarchicalStreamWriter writer,
        MarshallingContext context) {
     // TODO: Get annotation value from object 'source' with name of tag via Reflection.
     // Or add a method to the AnimalConfig interface giving you tag name to put to serialization output.
   }

   public Object unmarshal(HierarchicalStreamReader reader,
        UnmarshallingContext context) {
     // TODO: use reflection to create animal object based on what you xml tag you have at hahd.
     return context.convertAnother(context.currentObject(), SomeAnimalClazz.class);
   }

   public boolean canConvert(Class type) {
     return type.equals(AnimalConfig.class);
   }
 }
```

There's a disadvantage: polymorphism will require you to use Java Reflection API and performance degradation.

Comment: Another disavantage will be to do entire deserialization manually inside `unmarshall` method. If `CatConfig` or `DogConfig` are simple objects, everything should be fine, but if they contain nested objects, or lists, etc, he will loose the benefit of xstream automated deserialization. Or is there a way to "reconnect" automated deserialization for nested items ?

Comment: As soon as one derives class - one just have to pass it to context and call `convertAnother` which should do the trick. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 1):

This is quite easy. You just have to do it right and not like my previous speakers. When you process the annotations, XStream can assign those classes.

```
@XStreamAlias("person")
public class PersonConfig {

    private AnimalConfig animalConfig;

    public String toXml() {
        XStream xstream = new XStream();
        xstream.processAnnotations(DogConfig.class);
        xstream.processAnnotations(CatConfig.class);
        return xstream.toXML(this);
    }
}

public interface AnimalConfig {}

@XStreamAlias("dog");
public class DogConfig implements AnimalConfig {}

@XStreamAlias("cat");
public class CatConfig implements AnimalConfig {}
```

Answer (score 0):

It works out of the box, with out any annotations...

```
private static interface Test {
    String getName();

    Params getParams();
}

private static interface Params {
}

private static class OneParams implements Params {
    private String oneValue;

    public String getOneValue() {
        return oneValue;
    }

    public void setOneValue(String oneValue) {
        this.oneValue = oneValue;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append("OneParams [oneValue=");
        builder.append(oneValue);
        builder.append("]");
        return builder.toString();
    }

}

private static class TwoParams implements Params {
    private String twoValue;

    public String getTwoValue() {
        return twoValue;
    }

    public void setTwoValue(String twoValue) {
        this.twoValue = twoValue;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append("TwoParams [twoValue=");
        builder.append(twoValue);
        builder.append("]");
        return builder.toString();
    }

}

private static class OneTest implements Test {
    private String name;

    private Params params;

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public Params getParams() {
        return params;
    }

    public void setParams(Params params) {
        this.params = params;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append("OneTest [name=");
        builder.append(name);
        builder.append(", params=");
        builder.append(params);
        builder.append("]");
        return builder.toString();
    }

}
```

---- now deserialize like this...

```
    System.out
            .println(ser
                    .deserialize("<XStreamTest_-OneTest><name>OneTest</name><params class=\"XStreamTest$OneParams\"><oneValue>1</oneValue></params></XStreamTest_-OneTest>"));

    System.out
            .println(ser
                    .deserialize("<XStreamTest_-OneTest><name>TwoTest</name><params class=\"XStreamTest$TwoParams\"><twoValue>2</twoValue></params></XStreamTest_-OneTest>"));
```