# Xstream: a list with XStreamImplicit's itemFieldName but still wrapped in an element

Tags: java, jaxb, xstream

I have this class

```
@XStreamAlias("myConfig")
public class MyConfig {
    ... // other properties

    // What do I put here? 
    private List<String> includes;
}
```

And I want this output:

```
<myConfig>
    ...
    <includes>
        <includes>foo</include>
        <includes>bar</include>
    </includes>
</myConfig>
```

This doesn't work, because the  element is lost:

```
    @XStreamImplicit(itemFieldName = "include") // Loses <includes> element
    private List<String> includes;
```

Comment: Since your question is tagged with `jaxb` are you interested in the JAXB (JSR-222) solution?

Comment: @BlaiseDoughan Yes, jaxb too: I might consider switching from xstream to jaxb in the long run, because JAXB can generate an XSD.

Comment: Great, I have added an answer demonstrating how this can be done with a JAXB (JSR-222) implementation:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/14521810/383861

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your questions is tagged with [jaxb](/questions/tagged/jaxb) and based on your comment.

> @BlaiseDoughan Yes, jaxb too: I might consider switching from xstream
>   to jaxb in the long run, because JAXB can generate an XSD.

Here is what it would look like when using a [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) implementation:

```java
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement
public class MyConfig {

    private List<String> includes;

    @XmlElementWrapper
    @XmlElement(name = "include")
    public List<String> getIncludes() {
        return includes;
    }

    public void setIncludes(List<String> includes) {
        this.includes = includes;
    }

}
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/09/jaxb-collection-properties.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/10/how-does-jaxb-compare-to-xstream.html

Comment: Great stuff, especially the xstream vs jaxb comparison is beautiful :) Jaxb is looking more and more appealing. Out of scope for this question: My only "fear" with JAXB is that many app servers already have a jaxb version and I need my app to work on old app servers while using a just-released jaxb version. Is there any base to that fear?

Comment: @GeoffreyDeSmet - Some app servers provide mechanisms to override the version of the implementation of JAXB that is used.  Alternatively since JAXB is a standard (JSR-222) you could use a different provider (I'm the EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy) lead).  Is there a particular extension you need from the latest version?  Don't estimate the battle tested version already included.

Comment: BlaiseDoughan - Probably just uncertainty from my side indeed. Tnx for the info :) The only stuff I worry about so far is this @XmlElementWrapper, [the jaxb stuff I needed here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11484532/polymorphism-in-xstream-serialization-and-deserialization) and XSD generation. In any case, I 'll probably add an arquillian test to see if it works on old app servers (JBoss 5, Jetty 6 and tomcat 6).

Comment: @BlaiseDoughan Excellent links !

Answer (score 1):

To get the exact xml structure you are looking for, slight tweak needs to be done to your code.
Basically you need a Includes wrapper object that will have the list of values.

Here's my code that generates the xml

```
public class XSTreamAnnotTest {

    static class Includes {

        @XStreamImplicit(itemFieldName = "include")
        private List<String> include;

        Includes(List<String> include) {
            this.include = include;
        }
    }

    @XStreamAlias("myConfig")
    static class MyConfig {

        private Includes includes;

        public MyConfig(Includes includes) {
            this.includes = includes;
        }

    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        XStream stream = new XStream();
        stream.processAnnotations(MyConfig.class);
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("foo");
        list.add("bar");
        Includes cu = new Includes(list);

        MyConfig msg = new MyConfig(cu);
        System.out.println(stream.toXML(msg));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this is what I feared - the need for an extra class :)